# How can I hide my API keys for a Visual Studio Code Extension?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VS Code extension that relies on Google Cloud's Speech-to-Text API. Currently, I have the API key stored locally and out of my remote repository. Since VS Code extensions are deployed as .vsix files and can be unzipped, I am worried about potentially malicious users unpacking the .vsix and stealing my API keys. How can I keep the API keys hidden?

Comment: You can hide nothing there. Instead, you will have to either ask your users to set their own API key (via configuration), or set up a proxy layer somewhere (a web API to be called by your extension, which uses your API key to call Google's API).

Comment: Text-To-Speech can get very expensive quickly. I'm not sure you want thousands of users playing with a key linked to your credit card.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your API key as a secret in Google Secret Manager. Then you can access your secret, your API key, programatically. Besides you have a good integration between vscode and Secret Manager. You can have more details in this [Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/secret-manager).

Comment: Google Secret Manager seems to be a solution during development, but I am wondering about production. How would this work when I want to deploy the extension? It seems the best solution would be requiring my users to configure their own API key.